# UserSpace access to pages that are valid and mapped by a process

Tags: linux, paging, mmap, proc

if an application allocated 10GB not all pages will be allocated ( pages will be allocated using on demand paging when needed )

If i want to know what pages are actually valid and mapped . Do i need to traverse every page that is allocated by that process to check the valid bit ? or there is info in the /proc system or a mechanism to list the pages that are valid and mapped to the process without having to go to every page in the 10GB space to check

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to perform this check from userspace, as far as I know, the two main options you have are:

1. The [`mincore`](https://manned.org/mincore.2) syscall, which was implemented exactly for this purpose.
2. The virtual file `/proc/self/pagemap` (see its description under [`man 5 proc`](https://manned.org/proc.5)), which can be opened and read starting at the right offset to check.

In any case you will need to check every 4K page singularly.